# What notation marks that an activity must be completed within two-day time in an activity diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Customers can pay for an order instantly or later. When the order is pay-later, I want to draw a notation that signifies that the customer must pay within two-day time in an activity diagram. If the customer does not pay within two-day time, the system will mark the order as *canceled*.

In this attached image, the first swimlane is for the actor *Customer*, and the second swimlane is for the actor *System*. I created a *time event* notation that signifies that the customer must pay within 48 hours. Then, I placed the *merge/branch* node on the customer swimlane to signify that the customer is the actor that must make the payment.

[image: Activity Diagram Picture]

The issue that I thought of about my current diagram is that someone might misunderstand the time event notation. Someone might understand the notation as a sign that the system will always wait 48 hours before marking the order as *canceled* or *awaiting shipment*. In reality, the system will mark the order as *awaiting shipment* as soon as the customer pays. However, if the customer doesn't pay after 48 hours, the system will mark the order as *canceled*.

How can I draw a better diagram to signify the above description?

Comment: No time yet: exception handler in an interrputible region that triggers after that time.

Comment: @qwerty_so Something like [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095523/9060223)?

Comment: Not really. The timeout is the one breaking off the region into an exception handler. I had a similar answer, but where...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864533/activity-diagram-timed-event/65864713#65864713

Comment: @qwerty_so Why can't I use an Accept Event Action to indicate that the _System_ has accepted payment and proceeds with marking the order as _Awaiting Shipment_? Why must it be the Accept Time Event Action?

Comment: From my POV the timer event is an exception and should be treated as such. Treating the payment as exception sheds a bad light on the business ;-)

Comment: @qwerty_so I see. So anything with an interrupting edge subtly indicates that it's an exception condition?

Comment: Right. Zeus (or Donar) send their signals :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>An accept time event action (e.g. an *AcceptEventAction* with a single *TimeEvent* trigger) cannot have an input flow, so your diagram is invalid, and then does not show what you want.</s>

The guards of the flow after a *Decision* must be written between brackets (`[]`).

---

> I placed the merge/branch node on the customer swimlane to signify that the customer is the actor that must make the payment.

but this is check by the system independently of the customer, so this is wrong / unclear

The fact the two actions creating order are not in the customer swimlane is also wrong / unclear for me

---

After the action *create an order with the awaiting payment status* you can create a new timer dedicated to the current order of the customer. In case a customer pays before 2 days the corresponding timer is deleted.

But that can produce a lot of timers, you can also memorize the current order more timeout in a *fifo* and you have a unique timer. In case a customer pays before 2 days the corresponding order is removed from the *fifo*.

- That unique timer can periodically check the memorized orders, but that pooling wake-up the system even when nothing must be done.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- That unique timer can be started when a first order is memorized, then when the system wake-up it manages the too older orders, then if the fifo become empty the timer is stopped else it is updated depending on the delay of the first (older) order in the *fifo*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Who says WaitTimeAction cannot have an incoming ControlFlow? It just means, that the Activity will wait at this point until the time is up. If it is a relative time, it means that the clock will start running as soon as the Action is enabled.

Comment: I agree with you on the checks for whether an order has been paid or not. I will move the decision node in the _System's_ swimlane because it is indeed the System that will check if the payment has been made. For _Create Order_ actions, they are done by the _System_, so I think that I should keep them in the _System's_ swimlane.

Comment: Based on what I read [here on the Wait Time Action section](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-actions.html), it seems like _Wait Time Action_ can have incoming edges/control flows.

Comment: I have revised my answer, I think that I didn't crop enough of my diagram and the fact that I didn't caused confusion.

Comment: Your answer is very clear. Instead of using the wait time action, you're placing the _Awaiting Payment_ orders in a _queue_ and let the system check these, but is there a way to make the 3 diagrams to just one?

Comment: @Richard *is there a way to make the 3 diagrams to just one* : the 3 actions are separated, at a time the customer create an order with a later payment, at an other time the customer pay (or never), and at a time the system checks the orders requiring payment, this is why that need 3 diagrams.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer yes you are right, an an accept time event action can have or not an input flow, I edited my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Per [@qwerty_so's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/qwerty-so), I have decided to use an interruptible region. This interruption trigger of this region is the system accepting payment. Here's the new diagram.

[image: Revised Activity Diagram]

**EDIT**

As per [@bruno's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091488/what-notation-marks-that-an-activity-must-be-completed-within-two-day-time-in-an/67095523?noredirect=1#comment118597313_67095523) and [@Axel Scheithauer's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9430250/axel-scheithauer), I have cropped the more complete image of my activity diagram. [An Accept Time Event Action seems to be able to have incoming edges/flows](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html), contrary to @bruno's comments. Furthermore, I believe that the incomplete screenshot was what caused confusion in my diagram.

I also revised my diagram so that the interruptible region's signal comes from the Accept Time Event Action instead of Accept Event Action.

Diagram 1:
[image: Diagram]

Diagram 2:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: out of that the zigzag is missing from the output flow stating from the timer, and worst you block the system until the customer pay or during 2 days and I do not think this is what you want

Comment: @bruno: Actually the control flow starting from the wait time action does not need to be interrupting. As soon as the interuptible region doesn't contain any enabled action, all AcceptEventActions will get disabled. This is a special behavior just for them. The specification is a bit unclear about this, but the situation is analogous to structured activity nodes. I filed an issue about this long time ago.

Comment: Many people use swimlanes in this way. For my taste they mix two incompatible views: Are you defining a function of the system? Then what place do the actions of the user have in it? Are you defining the interaction of a user with a system? Then why do you specify, what happens inside the system? Additionally: If your swimlanes represent Classes or Actors, the UML says that they define the context of the _execution_ of the behavior defined by the action. The question is, who is _invoking_ the behavior? It is the context of the Activity itself. What is that in your example?

Comment: Swimlanes can mean whatever you like (unless you let them represent Classifiers). I guess you want to express who is reponsible for the _action_. Therefore, it doesn't make any difference, where you place the decision node. It is not an action and the activity itself is responsible for it. You could add an action `select payment mode` with a decision node following it.

Comment: @bruno Thanks for answering, but [the text here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html) suggests that a _Wait Time Action_ or an _Accept Time Event Action_ can have incoming edges/control flows.

Comment: @bruno Regarding the interrupting edge being missing from the timer, my bad. I will revise my answer, please take a look at it again.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer For the activity diagram, I'm trying to show the viewer of the diagram what the customer should do to place an order. However, at the same time, I want to show what important events also occur inside the system when the customer does such action.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer *Actually the control flow starting from the wait time action does not need to be interrupting* in the OP case it is because the flow has its source within the interruptible activity region and its target out of it (cf §15.6.3.2 Interruptible Activity Regions)

Comment: @Richard yes an accept time event action can have an input flow, I was wrong, I read bad the standard

Comment: @Richard in your second diagram as I said in a remark before your edit you block the system (or the current thread) during 2 days if the customer does not pay, I do not think this is what you want

Comment: @bruno I see, but if we're talking about threads, I'm not that familiar. However, I know that in Kotlin, we can simply launch a new thread-like thing called coroutines to handle a suspending (blocking) function (in this case, the Accept Time Event Action). Thus, the system is not blocked even when the customer does not pay for 2 days.

Comment: @bruno For diagram 1, I see that an _Accept Event Action_ signifies an asynchronous process. So there should be no problem with it. For the _Accept Time Event Action_, can the same logic of launching another coroutine be applied, thus not blocking the system's other threads' execution?

Comment: @Richard you block the system/thread associated to the initial flow (the decision node with 2 output flow depending on the immediate / later payment) while that one whatever the used way does not reach a final node. The fact you have a timer changes nothing about that. So again in your case you block it during 2 days if the customer does not pay.

Comment: I think both diagrams are fine. In the case of the user not paying it _is_ the intention that the system is blocked for two days. During these two days, a wait time action and an accept signal action (diagram 1) or one action on the user side and the wait time action (diagram 2) are enabled. In the first case, the Activity is at a wait point, where one of two events can happen, whichever comes first. So no threads are necessary. In the second case, one is a user action, who has his/her own thread anyway.

Comment: There is a slight problem with the second diagram. Something in the system is supposed to interrupt an action on the user side. How is this accomplished? Probably we just assume, that `make payment` takes zero time, so it can never be interrupted. You have to decide, whether this simplification is justified.